# Best meme for today's system message?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, system-message

I guess it would have been better if today was a Friday, but this just got started in the office, so have at it before this question gets closed.

[image]

Comment: Occupy the System Message!

Comment: [Popcorn anyone?](http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/hh2td/a_moderator_in_rstarcraft_has_banned_a_user_for/c1vcdom "http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/aq8ak/bookmarklet_to_show_all_images_on_a_reddit/")

Comment: [already hit it in the lounge](http://i.imgur.com/X1Zm0.jpg).  I'll let the community close this for ya.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Censored by SOPA]

Comment: I think we'll need a bigger system message bar.

Comment: @TimPost Yes!  They should definitely make it bigger and allow us to post clickable images in there!  Then all the arguing about it would stop.  ;)

Comment: @BilltheLizard - hmmm, perhaps, they could make it dismissable using some sort of "chased off the screen by a unicorn" animation. I'd totally be ok with it then.